# WSO2 Installation

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am in the installation process WSO2 tool regarding: https://wso2.com/api-management/install/docker-compose/get-started/

Getting the following error:

On command: `docker-compose up --build`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon     790B
Step 1/4 : FROM docker.wso2.com/wso2am:4.0.0.0
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.451kB
Step 1/3 : FROM docker.wso2.com/wso2mi:4.0.0.0
2 errors occurred:
        * Status: pull access denied for docker.wso2.com/wso2am, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1
        * Status: pull access denied for docker.wso2.com/wso2mi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1
```

Any idea how can I pass this step?

Comment: Do you have the wso2 subscription? As far I understand, the out-of-box docker images are updated (patched) often and the subscription credentials are needed to access them. You can still create your own images from the open source releases.

Answer (score 4):

You need a WSO2 Subscription to access the internal docker repository (i.e. docker.wso2.com). However, as a workaround, you can set the base image in the relevant Dockerfiles to the publicly available GA image.

For example, if you plan to run docker-compose for apim-with-analytics, update [1] to

```
FROM wso2/wso2am:4.0.0
```

This will pull the GA image from the public repository. Please note that this won't have any post release updates.

[1]- https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/blob/master/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics/dockerfiles/apim/Dockerfile#L20

Comment: I have WSO2 Subscription, and successfully logged in by command:  docker login docker.wso2.com. Also in all Dockerfiles, I found "FROM wso2/wso2am:4.0.0". But issue happening

Comment: If you have a valid WSO2 subscription, you don't need to change the base images. Can you try the command `docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am:4.0.0.0` separately and see whether you can pull the image?

Comment: Command: docker pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am:4.0.0.0
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker.wso2.com/wso2am, 
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: But Command: docker pull wso2/wso2am, passed successfully

Comment: docker.io(dockerhub) and docker.wso2.com are two different repos. You can't use dockerhub credentials to login to docker.wso2.com. You need the credentials given by wso2 to access this. You can pull from wso2/wso2am because thats the public repo in dockerhub.

Comment: I see. Thank you!